# flutter doesn't load more users don't know why

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I'm trying to load more users with pagination, it should only show 20 users and load new ones when the end of the screen is reached, but `widget.loadMoreEndOfScroll` gets returned null when it shouldn't, I don't know what else could be wrong, other times it worked a few times and than it stopped working and only showing 20 instead of loading new ones.

so this is the class what I use

```
class CAScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const CAScaffold({
    Key? key,
    this.canLoadMoreEndOfScroll,
    this.loadMoreEndOfScroll,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool? canLoadMoreEndOfScroll;
  final Function? loadMoreEndOfScroll;

  @override
  State<CAScaffold> createState() => _CAScaffoldState();
}

this is the listener below

class _CAScaffoldState extends State<CAScaffold> {

  ScrollController scrollUsersController = ScrollController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollUsersController.addListener(() {
      if(scrollUsersController.offset >= scrollUsersController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
          !scrollUsersController.position.outOfRange &&
          widget.canLoadMoreEndOfScroll != null && widget.canLoadMoreEndOfScroll!) {
        print('endofscroll ${widget.loadMoreEndOfScroll}');
        if(widget.loadMoreEndOfScroll != null) {
          print('loadMoreEndOfScroll ${widget.loadMoreEndOfScroll}');
          widget.loadMoreEndOfScroll!();
        }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

here it gets called and will call the getAllUsers function

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CAScaffold(
    canLoadMoreEndOfScroll: loadingUsers == false && allUsersLoaded == false,
    loadMoreEndOfScroll: () {
      getAllUsers();
      newSearch = false;
    },
    pageTitle: 'Accounts',
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        BlocConsumer<AccountScreenCubit, AccountScreenState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if(state is AccountScreenLoadingUsersState) {
              loadingUsers = true;
            }
            if(state is AccountScreenUsersError) {
              loadingUsers = false;
            }
            if(state is AccountScreenUsersLoaded) {
              users.addAll(state.users);
              print(state.users.length);
              loadingUsers = false;
              if(state.users.isEmpty) {
                allUsersLoaded = true;
              }
            }
          },

getAllUsers function

void getAllUsers() {
  if(loadingUsers == false && allUsersLoaded == false) {
    context.read<AccountScreenCubit>().getUsers(
      searchTerm: searchInput,
      orderFilter: dropDownValue,
      newSearch: newSearch,
    );
  }
}

and than it gets send to the cubit

class AccountScreenCubit extends Cubit<AccountScreenState> {
  AccountScreenCubit() : super(AccountScreenInitial());

  QuerySnapshot? lastDocument;

  Future<void> getUsers({String? searchTerm, bool newSearch = true, String? orderFilter}) async {
    if(newSearch){
      lastDocument = null;
    }
    try {
      emit(AccountScreenLoadingUsersState());
      await FirestoreUserHelper.getAllUsersOrderedByName(
        20,
        searchTerm: searchTerm,
        orderFilter: orderFilter,
        lastSnapshot: lastDocument,
      ).then((FirestoreReturn value) {
        if(value.success) {
          if(value.snapshot != null) {
            lastDocument = value.snapshot;
          }
          emit(AccountScreenUsersLoaded(users: value.returnMain));
        } else {
          emit(AccountScreenUsersError(errorMsg: value.errorMessage));
        }
      });
    } catch(e) {
      emit(AccountScreenUsersError(errorMsg: 'Something went wrong: $e'));
    }
  }
}
```

if there is something I have missed let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not calling the `getAllUsers` function because you forgot the brackets, so add them.

   ```
   loadMoreEndOfScroll: () {
     getAllUsers();
     newSearch = false;
   },
   ```
2. You probably have to put `CAScaffold` inside `BlocConsumer`, otherwise parameter `canLoadMoreEndOfScroll: loadingUsers == false && allUsersLoaded == false,` is never updated.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, I've done what you said and put CAScaffold inside the BLocConsumer, it doesn't make a difference but adding the brackets did, now it loads the same 20 users twice and than it shows the last 16, any idea why this might be happening? and in the CAScaffold we only check if it has that value we don't update it